# Intellisense for a property in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, designer, propertygrid

I am hiding a property from property grid using `Browsable(false)` attribute. It also removes the intellisense for the property in aspx page.

Is there a way to show intellisense for the property in aspx page ?

**Code for property**

```
public new string Height
{
    get{ return m_height; }
    set{ m_height = value; }
}
```

**Note**

1. Changing the type from `string` to `Unit` works. But I am not allowed to change the type of `Height` to `Unit`. Because it is a breaking change
2. Using `Browsable(true)` works but changing the value of `Height` in property grid throws "Ambiguous match found error".

**Things I have tried**

1) Using `PreFilterProperties` override method of `ControlDesigner`

Intellisense is appearing but if I change the value of Height property in aspx page, designer is not updating the control. On debugging I found that the property is not being watched by designer.

```
        //Height will be removed from property window
        protected override void PreFilterProperties(System.Collections.IDictionary properties)
        {
            base.PreFilterProperties(properties);

            //Do not show Height in property grid
            properties["Height"] = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof(MyControl), (PropertyDescriptor)properties["Height"], BrowsableAttribute.No);

        }
```

Please share your suggestions